# Scan whole line from file in C Programming

Tags: c, eol

I was writing a program to input multiple lines from a file.
the problem is i don't know the length of the lines, so i cant use fgets cause i need to give the size of the buffer and cant use fscanf cause it stops at a space token
I saw a solution where he recommended using malloc and realloc for each character taken as input but i think there's an easier way and then i found someone suggesting using

```
fscanf(file,"%[^\n]",line);
```

Does anyone have a better solution or can someone explain how the above works?(i haven't tested it)

i use GCC Compiler, if that's needed

Comment: I'm curious: Why, exactly, can't you use `fgets()`? I didn't understand your explanation above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getline(3)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=getline&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html).  It allocates memory on your behalf, which you should free when you are finished reading lines.

Comment: thanks going through the syntax never knew about this function

Comment: I never knew about this either. It reminds me of strdup() which is tr best way to copy a string.

Comment: Beware that the returned string includes the line ending itself.

Answer (score 1):

> and then i found someone suggesting using `fscanf(file,"%[^\n]",line);`

That's practically an unsafe version of `fgets(line, sizeof line, file);`. Don't do that.

If you don't know the file size, you have two options.

1. There's a `LINE_MAX` macro defined somewhere in the C library (AFAIK it's POSIX-only, but some implementations may have equivalents). It's a fair assumption that lines don't exceed that length.
2. You can go the "read and realloc" way, but you don't have to `realloc()` for every character. A conventional solution to this problem is to exponentially expand the buffer size, i. e. always double the allocated memory when it's exhausted.

Comment: Expanding on to #2 above, use `fgets` repeatedly on the aforementioned geometric-expansion buffer until such time as the last char read is, in fact, newline. or `fgets` fails due to EOF (or any other reason, for that matter). +1

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks. Yes, that's right. Viva 2985775737-character-long lines! :P

Comment: 1. Isn't the unused space a waste in this assumption, also generally it can also be insufficient (edited for typo)

Comment: 2. Yeah sticking to that now . will keep checking this page for better solutions

Comment: @KarthikNayak 1. No, not a waste. Just don't think about optimization in first place, OK? 2.

Comment: @H2CO3 if you say so :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple format specifier for scanf or fscanf follows this prototype

```
%specifier
```

specifiers

As we know `d` is format specifier for integers  Like this

`[characters]` is `Scanset` Any number of the characters specified between the brackets.
 A dash (-) that is not the first character may produce non-portable behavior in some library implementations.

`[^characters]` is 
    `Negated scanset` Any number of characters none of them specified as characters between the brackets.

---

```
fscanf(file,"%[^\n]",line);
```

Read any characters till occurance of any charcter in `Negated scanset` in this case `newline character`

---

As others suggested you can use  [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) or [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fgets.html) and see [example](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx6c.html)

Answer (score 0):

The line `fscanf(file,"%[^\n]",line);`  means that it will read anything other than `\n` into `line`. This should work in Linux and Windows, I think. But may not work in OS X format which use `\r` to end a line.

Comment: We are in 2013. OS X no longer uses `\r`. Also, it's definitely a bad idea to do this, especially since we don't know the line size. Very prone to buffer overrun errors.