# How to use "scanf" to input specific letter?

Tags: c, regex, scanf

from my knowledge in high school.

```
scanf("%[^A-Z]s", input);
```

it is mean input can be any characters but except capital letter.

but in case of i want to receive input only character [A-F] how can i do it?

in my sense it should be written like this:

```
scanf("%[A-Z]s", input);
```

It looks like you use regex but anyway it was't work

So, when i run it

```
$./a.out 
asdfasdfABC 
`[]@
```

[] is some alien character but i can not type.

Comment: Have you tried just like that, e.g. `"%[A-Z]"`?

Comment: i tried already. but output has some alien letter.

Comment: Show code that actually demonstrates your problem and your "alien letter".

Comment: @KKKKK see [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410106/scan-whole-line-from-file-in-c-programming/19410272#19410272) might helpful

Comment: It isn't a 'regex', though it is similar to a character class as specified in a regex. It is called a 'scanset' in the documentation for [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html). Note too that the `s` after it is trying to match a literal 's'; it is not part of the conversion specification. The conversion specification is `%[^A-Z]` or `%[A-F]`. Check that the scan call matched the correct number of values. A scanset reads a string of characters until something fails to match: `%63[A-F]` to read a string of up to 63 letters A-F (for `char input[64];`).

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can simply write code as

```
    scanf("%[A-F]s", input);
```

now input would carry only from A to F.

Comment: The `scanf("%[A-F]s", input)` would eat the `s` if the input was `Fs`; if the input was `Fa`, the `a` would be left untouched.  The `s` is not part of the scanset conversion specification — you either use `%s` or `%[...]` but not both in a single conversion specification.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, most likely, that you do not check for errors, and print the string even when the `scanf` call fails.

With the pattern `"%[A-Z]"` you only scan for uppercase letters, and if the string you input doesn't begin with upper case letters `scan` will fail. This of course means that the string `input` will never be filled, and will contain random data which you then print.

I recommend you read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). It will tell you that the function will return the number of items successfully scanned, which should be `1` in your case. If the `scanf` function in your code doesn't return `1` then there is a problem.

So you need to do something like

```
if (scanf(...) == 1)
    printf(...);
else
    printf("Something went wrong when reading input\n");
```