# how to make this program only accept lowercase letter but in string

Tags: c, string

How to make this program only accept lowercase letter . Im stuck here pls help

C

```
char x[4] = "iss";
char y[31];
scanf("%30s", & y);
if (y >= "A" && y <= "Z") {

  if ((strstr(x, y) == 0)) {
    printf("hiss");
  } else {
    printf("no hiss");
  }
}
```

Comment: so how to make the if work?

Comment: i dont know how to make the if statement to accept only lowercase letter

Comment: You're looking for `islower()`, which is declared in `<ctype.h>`.  Testing character values with `<` and similar is non-portable (not all codings have contiguous letters).

Comment: i need the program not to lower the letter but i want to just scan the lowercase letter. If the input any upper case the program will not load them

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Toby....You could use the "tolower" function available in the "ctype.h" library.

Am not sure if you are checking the existence of "hiss" in the input stream---you can modify the code to suit your need.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char x[4] = "iss";
  char y[31];
  int i = 0;
  scanf("%30s", y);
  while(y[i]){
    y[i] = tolower(y[i]);
    i++;
  }

  if ((strstr(y, x) != NULL)) { //checking the existence of "hiss" in the input stream
    printf("hiss");
  } 
  else {
    printf("no hiss");
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: i need the program to scan just lower case letter. If they input any upper cases the program wont load

Comment: In that case you could use something like scanf("%30[^A-Z]s",y) or scanf("%30[a-z]s",y)......Would suggest going through [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569545/how-to-use-scanf-to-input-specific-letter)